# How does ubuntu update to debian?

Tags: upgrade, debian

When ubuntu update to debian,

Which packages to update,

From where to know what updated and what main package updated.

And also like to know what strongly not move to debian.

Comment: Ubuntu and Debian are two different Linux distros.

Comment: Do not play politics, straight forward answer for given questation. Ubuntu base is debian, ubuntu it-self born from debian, how better you updating debian and their packages & deliver security and feature inside it ? I had seen some of closed and narrow minded people hold the question.

Comment: It is not clear if the user is asking  
how does Ubuntu manage software updates (being based on Debian and having inherited it's package manager)?, or  
how does the Ubuntu maintenance teams organize their repositories (how does it compare to Debian)?, or  
how can he Update his existing Ubuntu installation to a Debian setup (changing package sources)?

Indeed the OP could have edited the question and it would be easier to answer something useful.

Fortunately SE is great at suggesting Related questions to look at.

Answer (score 2):

As you can see in the comment, Debian and Ubuntu are different Linux distributions. Ubuntu is based in Debian, but it not upgradeable to it. You can upgrade Ubuntu to a newest version of Ubuntu like 14.04 or 15.04. Debian in the other hand, is in the 8.1 version. Both are really good systems, but you can look at:

[Debian](https://www.debian.org/)

And here: [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop)

For more information. Search on google with something like: "Ubuntu vs Debian" or something else to see some comparative information

Comment: this I can found in google too, but I need to know how frequent ubuntu update dabian package and security & more

Comment: On Ubuntu, you can view weekly software updates, depending on which packages you have installed. On  any new software update release, the system will notify you for a new update immediately. Sometimes, you can see package updates near to tow times per week.

Comment: Read questation, its not about Ubuntu only, its about ubuntu  push update,patch, libs, security to debian.

Comment: I'm not a Debian expert, but the way to update on Debian is the same as Ubuntu, so, use sudo apt-get update. I have used Debian for some time, and also as ubuntu, Debian notify you of regular software updates almost weekly. Because Ubuntu is Based on Debian, it may be, an update release for certain package is available for both at almost the same time. You do not need to do anything manually, because the OS will notify you on any new  available update.